# message is not defined discord.js slashcommands

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm getting an error saying that I'm not defining `message`

```
content: `Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms.`,
                                                              ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

```
const Discord  = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '.';

const fs = require('fs');

const guildId = ''

const getApp = (guildId) => {
    const app = client.api.applications(client.user.id)
    if (guildId) {
        app.guilds(guildId)
    }
    return app
}

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', async () => {
    console.log('HenBot Is Online!');

    const commands = await getApp(guildId).commands.get()
    console.log(commands)

    await getApp(guildId).commands.post({
        data: {
            name: 'ping',
            description: 'Bots Latency',
        },
    })

    client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async (interaction, message) => {
        const slashCommmand = interaction.data.name.toLowerCase()

        if(slashCommmand === 'ping') {
            client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
                data: {
                    type: 4,
                    data: {
                        content: `Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms.`,
                    },
                },
            })
        }
    })
})

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {  
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s because `message` is not a valid parameter for `interactionCreate`.

As the discord.js docs implies, you can only pass in `interaction` in an `interactionCreate` event.

This should work for your code:

```
content: `Latency is ${Date.now() - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms.`,
```

Comment: Actually it's `interaction.createdTimestamp`, check it [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Interaction?scrollTo=createdTimestamp)

Comment: my bad, thanks for catching that typo.

Comment: `Latency is NaNms`. didn't work as well, it says `interaction` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`interactionCreate` event cannot have `message` parameter...

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
      // your code here
})
```

Comment: The application did not respond

Comment: and i changed message to interaction, still didnt work

Comment: change the whole event it is wrong, here read the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#receiving-interactions)

Comment: it was not, im using older discord.js 12.2.0 cuz of older tutorial series and it worked before after changing it, it didnt work